# Hiding the R line number in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm outputting a simple variable in R Markdown. I tried different options to hide the R compiler line number, but it keeps displaying:

`````
```{r echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE}
var = 1000
```

This is my output: 
```{r echo=FALSE} 
print(r)
````
`````

The output looks like this:

```
This is my output:
## [1] 1000
```

How can I get rid of ## [1]?

Comment: Use `cat(r)` instead.

Comment: Doesn't work, it still shows ##

Comment: Now I get ## [1] 1000
## 1000
rather than a single ## [1] 1000!

Comment: Can you please reopen this question?

Comment: I replaced it with a different duplicate for when you want to get rid of the "##" part.